# File Size Error in php

Tags: php

I am doing a validation of files upload in php. I want to validate a file

`if > 3MB: display error`.

`else: proceed to upload`

what i'm doing now is, if file size is more or less than 3 MB, it display the error. below are the codes:

```
/*
* other validation of post here
*
*/
if (isset($_FILES['uploaded'])) {
    $filesize = $_FILES['uploaded']['size']; 
    if ($filesize > 3145728) {
        $msgError[] = 'File can not be more than 3MB';  
    }
    for ($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['uploaded']['name']); $i++) {
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'][$i];
        if (!empty($tmpFilePath)) {
            $shortname = $_FILES['uploaded']['name'][$i];
            $filePath = "uploads/" . date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][$i];
            if (!$msgError && move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)) {
                $sql = " UPDATE purchase SET quotation_1='".date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][0]."', quotation_2='".date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][1]."', quotation_3='".date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][2]."' 
                WHERE pr_id='$pr_id' ";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
                    mysqli_close($conn); 
                    $pr_idEnc = urlencode(encryptor('encrypt', $pr_id)); 
                    header("Location: ".BASE_PATH."update-purchase.php?success&pr_id=".$pr_idEnc."");
                } else {
                    mysqli_close($conn); 
                    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
                }
            } else {
                $msgErrorString = implode(",",$msgError); 
                $pr_idEnc = urlencode(encryptor('encrypt', $pr_id)); 
                mysqli_close($conn);
                header("Location: ".BASE_PATH."update-purchase.php?pr_id=".$pr_idEnc."&msgError=".$msgErrorString."");
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: you should kill the  page here `if ($filesize > 3145728) {
        $msgError[] = 'File can not be more than 3MB';  
    }`

Comment: do you mean I have to change to `die('File can not be more than 3MB');`

Comment: i mean call exit; or die after ` $msgError[] = 'File can not be more than 3MB'; exit;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not change `upload_max_filesize` and `upload_max_filesize` settings in `php.ini` file?

```
upload_max_filesize  = 3 M
post_max_size = 3 M
```

**post_max_size**

> Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than
>   upload_max_filesize. Generally speaking, memory_limit should be larger
>   than post_max_size. When an integer is used, the value is measured in
>   bytes.

**upload_max_filesize**

> The maximum size of an uploaded file. When an integer is used, the
>   value is measured in bytes.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `=`, not `-`? Also, default `upload_max_filesize` is 2MB so your answer is somewhat relevant but `post_max_size` default IS 8MB and shouldn't configured lower.

Comment: Thanks @lacobus, managed to get it done after I change the code above. Is it ok if change the `post_max_size` in future use?

Comment: @Amran `post_max_size` could be changed, but the value must be larger than `upload_max_filesize` and not exceed `memory_limit` value.